# Sudoers.d file is not picking up in SLES SP5

Tags: linux, sudo, sles

I was working with some Linux service file and in one scenario I need to invoke **systemctl** command as a different user say **sar** user. So I have wrote one sudoers file(/etc/sudoers.d) and added the following code

```
%sar ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/dmidecode -t system, /usr/bin/chmod, /usr/bin/systemctl

Defaults:sar !requiretty
```

and I am invoking the command using **sudo** prefix

its working for the most of the Linux version but in SLES 12 SP5 its not picking sudoers file, so I am getting **sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified**

Linux machine specs
`NAME="SLES" VERSION="12-SP5" VERSION_ID="12.5" PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5" ID="sles" ANSI_COLOR="0;32" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp5"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the "%" from the beginning of the sudoers file, In SLES distribution it not considered as a valid format

```
sar ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/dmidecode -t system, /usr/bin/chmod, /usr/bin/systemctl

Defaults:sar !requiretty
```

Comment: This solution is working in SLES and all other distributions